# Watch + pipe + multiple arguments

Tags: bash, diff, sh, escape-characters, watch

I have a command `diff -y <(xxd FILE) <(xxd FILE_) | colordiff` and i want to put it into `watch` routine. Something like that:

```
watch -n 0,1 'diff -y <(xxd FILE) <(xxd FILE_)'
```

But i have an error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use bash syntaxes, then run it with bash:

```
$ watch -n 0,1 'bash -c "diff -y <(xxd FILE) <(xxd FILE_)"'
```